# Question about std::less behavior

Tags: c++, gcc, stl

What is happening there?

```
#include <functional>

namespace A {
    struct Class { };
}

bool operator<(const A::Class& a, const A::Class& b)
{ return false; }

int main()
{
    std::less<A::Class>()(A::Class(), A::Class());
    return 0;
}
```

This is compiled ok. But if I use.

```
#include <set>
```

I got errors:

```
g++     test.cc   -o test
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_tree.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include/g++-v4/set:60,
                 from lookup.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_function.h: In member function 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = A::Class]':
test.cc:15:49:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_function.h:230:22: error: no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup

Comment: @dalle: ADL is only part of the answer - the fact that `less` uses `std::operator<` is far more relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason that the lookup fails is that `set` introduces an `operator<` for `std::set` in the `std` namespace that hides all other global `operator<`.

The lookup of `<` in the instantiation of `std::less` happens inside a scope inside the `std` namespace. The only way that any `operator<` outside of `std` namespace will become visible is if ADL kicks into action and this only happens for the nearest enclosing namespace.

Without including `<set>`, there is no `operator<` introduced (and this is probably implementation dependent) in the `std` namespace that hides the global `operator<` and hence the non-ADL lookup rules can still find the global `operator<` which take `A::Class`.

**Correction:** As @JohannesSchaub points out, this analysis would only be correct if the declaration of `operator<` occurred before `<functional>` (where `std::less` is defined) was first included. As it is, the only overloads of a function called through an *unqualified-id* that should be visible to non-ADL lookup inside a template definition are those visible at the point of definition. Definitions introduced between the point of definition and the point of instantiation should only be visible for ADL lookup. (In an expression such as `x < y` candidate functions named `operator<` are searched for and this is one particular form of *unqualified-id*.)

As it stands, the overloaded `operator<` should not be considered a candidate with or without the `<set>` include, although these corner cases in the lookup rules are not always handled correctly by all compilers.

Comment: @Charles Bailey I don't understand. What kind of `operator<` can  hide global one? Any operator for other type?

Comment: @AshotMartirosyan: Yes, in this example, the `operator<` template for `set` in `std` hides all other `operator<` at global scope when `operator<` is looked up in the `std` namespace.

Comment: OK, I got it. Here I put some code showing how this problem is occurring http://ideone.com/cfj9I

Comment: Now I understand, too!  But... why the heck did `std::less` introduce `std::operator<`?

Comment: @xtofl: The general `std::less` template uses `<` in its implementation. It can be explicitly specialized (either by the implementation or by the user for user-defined types), but the default implementation "just works" if you can use `<` on the given type.

Comment: But you _can_ use `<` for `A::Class`, can't you?  So I'm confused again: why doesn't _this_ code "just work"?

Comment: @xtofl: That's what I explained (or tried to explain!) in my original answer. You can do, so long as the correct `operator<` is visible. Inside the definition of `std::less`, where `<` is used, any `std::operator<` will hide all global `operator<` _unless_ they are re-introduced via ADL.

Comment: His compiler should have already rejected the first version of his code, because he declared `operator<` not in `A::` (so it is not found by ADL), and because he declared his `operator<` after including `<functional>` (so `operator<` is not found by unqualified name lookup in the definition of `std::less`).

Answer (score 5):

That `operator<` should be in `namespace A` as well, otherwise it cannot be looked up.

Details:
First of all, simply calling `operator<` on two `Class` objects from `main()`, or even implementing your own `less` of course works whether `operator<` is in the same namespace as `Class` or not, although it **should** be in the same namespace since that's what everyone, including the implementors of the libraries, expects. Both gcc and MSVC 2010 (as I just tested) include several additional `operator<`'s in their standard libraries, between which the compiler fails to resolve.

gcc 4.5.2's error message is misleading. Compiling the same with a pre-release 4.6, I get the more specific

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_tree.h:65:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/set:60,
                 from test.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_function.h: In member function 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = A::Class]':
test.cc:9:42:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_function.h:234:22: error: no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_function.h:234:22: note: candidates are:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_pair.h:205:67: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_iterator.h:290:46: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_iterator.h:340:47: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_tree.h:847:70: note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_set.h:712:46: note: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0-alpha20110115/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_multiset.h:695:51: note: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
```

Incidentally, SunCC (with both rw and stlport4) compiles this cleanly and even creates a usable `std::set<A::Class>`.

Comment: In other words: why _can_ it be looked up when `<set>` is _not_ included?

Answer (score 3):

Your `operator<` overload needs to be in the same namespace as `Class` (that is, it also needs to be in the `A` namespace).

C++ has complex name lookup rules.  One of the more interesting "features" is "argument-dependent lookup," or ADL, where names can be looked up in namespaces associated with a function's arguments.  For a class that has no base classes and isn't a nested class, like your `Class`, the only associated namespace is the namespace within which the class is located.

So, the only namespace associated with `Class` is `A`, so only the `A` namespace is searched during argument-dependent lookup for an `operator<` overload.

[Charles Bailey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921741/question-about-stdless-behavior/4922047#4922047) provides a good explanation of why you only see the problem when including `<set>`.

Comment: ADL doesn't inhibit normal lookup, it is in addition to it.